# Kubernetes shared persistent volume between multiple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, persistent-storage

I am currently looking into setting up Kubernetes pods for a project on GCP.

The problem - I need to set a persistent shared volume which will be used by multiple nodes. I need all nodes to be able to read from the volume and only one node must be able to write on the volume. So I need some advice what's the best way to achieve that?

I have checked the Kubernetes documentation and know that `GCEPersistentDisks` does not support `ReadWriteMany` but anyway this access mode I think will be an overkill. Regarding the `ReadOnlyMany` I get that nodes can read from the PV but I don't understand how or what can actually modify the PV in this case. Currently my best bet is setting up NFS with GCE persistent disk.

Also the solution should be able to run on the cloud or on premise. Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

According to official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

> A PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping.
>
> A volume can only be mounted using one access mode at a time, even if
>   it supports many. For example, a GCEPersistentDisk can be mounted as
>   ReadWriteOnce by a single node or ReadOnlyMany by many nodes, but not
>   at the same time.

So I am afraid that this would be impossible to do it how you described.

However, you may want to try [task queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/)

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some NFS space availalbe, it could be possible to create two persistent volume claims (PVCs) for it: one readonly, one readwrite.
Then you could have two persistent volumes binding one to one to each of the PVCs.

Now create two deployments. One of them describes the pod with the writing application, and you ensure you have one replica. The other deployment describes the reading application, and you can scale it to whatever amount you like.